# How to make an objects’s property raise a user-defined runtime fatal error?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I need a “Let” property of an object to raise a user-defined runtime error (number and description defined by me) if the passed parameter is not within the range of acceptable values. I can get the property to raise the error but I cannot get the error to bear the number and description I have defined. Here is a simplified example :

```
' Class Module: myPerson

Private m_Age As Integer

Property Let Age(yearsOld As Integer)

If yearsOld >= 0 Then
        m_Age = yearsOld
Else
        Err.Clear 'Make sure we start from a clean slate
        Err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 513, Source:="Book1.myPerson.LetAge", Description:="Positive integer required"
End If
    
End Property

Property Get Age() As Integer
    Age = m_Age
End Property

'Normal Module 1

Sub use_myPersonClass()

    Dim aPerson As myPerson
    
    Set aPerson = New myPerson
    
    aPerson.Age = -1 'Raises a runtime error but not my user-defined runtime error

End Sub
```

I do not understand the expression “vbObjectError + 513” – I do not understand why on earth adding 513 to -2147221504 would conveniently contribute to the definition of my personal error number – but I do not care : I am just following what the documentation tells me to do and, after all, the definition of the error number is not my main problem.
My main problem is that I do not get my personal description of the error. What I get as an error is :

[image: enter image description henter image description hereere]

Any hint on why this happens and how I could correct ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. For me the error message shows "Positive integer required". Your err.raise looks ok ...

Comment: What happens if simply put the Err.Raise statement in the immediate window and execute?

Comment: What version of Excel ? Windows or Mac ?

Comment: This happens on Excel for Mac 16.78.3 (latest)

Comment: If I execute the Err.Raise from the immediate window I get a dialog : "Microsoft Visual Basic <crlf> Run-time error '-2147220991 (80040201)': <crlf> Positive integer required". At least I have my description displayed (the error number is still cryptic and the source is not displayed). At this point it is unclear to me how to use that result as a hint for a solution of my problem. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Apply this workaround in you normal Module code.

```
'Normal Module 1

Sub use_myPersonClass()

    Dim aPerson As myPerson

    Set aPerson = New myPerson
    On Error Resume Next
    aPerson.Age = -1 'Raises a runtime error but not my user-defined runtime error
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error:  " & Err.Number - vbObjectError & Chr(10) & Err.Description, , Err.Source
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    

End Sub
```

**More details about Err.Raise**

This method works as fully desired only in a standard Module.

This is the result  when the Err.Raise method is in a standard module.

[image]

In all other modules (Class,Sheet) the Err. object parameters are filled with the assigned values, but the message which is generated by the error not reflects them.

However the assigned values are stored in the Err object and the snippet shows that all the assigned values are there which were declared in the Class module's command, and can be achieved with the Err object properties.

The `Description` parameter is not reflected in the error message, this is for information and can get with Err.Description.

If the same command is placed in another module than a standard one,  the error message reflects only the correct number (user-defined) and some other description (in-built) of the error. This is what you experienced.  Really this is not too good.

To use vbObjectError constant as the base of the user defined error is a recommendation to avoid  referencing to an in-built error code.

Comment: Thanks Black Cat, that's one way to work around the problem I encountered. Actually, instead of "On Error Resume Next" the execution can be redirected to an error handler routine that then raises a runtime error with the desired description.

Comment: @nunof Pls. find my adding of  some details to my answer

Answer (score 1):

As it should not be the responsibility of the routine using an object to detect that the object does not like the way it is being used, I suggest, building on the contribution of Black cat above, to work around the problem I am experiencing in the following manner :

```
' Class Module: myPerson

Private m_Age As Integer

Property Let Age(yearsOld As Integer)

If yearsOld >= 0 Then
        m_Age = yearsOld
Else
        MsgBox ("Object myPerson Property Let Age : invalid parameter, positive integer required")
        'This message to compensate for the VBA limitation documented below
        Err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 513, Source:="Book1.myPerson.LetAge", Description:="Positive integer required" 'Fatal runtime error raised
        'Limitation of VBA (on macOS ?) : none of the properties of the Err object specified above is displayed correctly
End If

End Property

Property Get Age() As Integer
    Age = m_Age
End Property

'Normal Module 1

Sub use_myPersonClass()

    Dim aPerson As myPerson
    
    Set aPerson = New myPerson
    
    aPerson.Age = -1 'Raises a runtime error

End Sub
```

Cheers,

nunof